# How to convert QGuiApplication to QApplication in QtCreator 10 with Qt 6?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt-creator, qtcharts

I'm trying to use `PolarChartView` but when I run my code , my application crashed and the qt creator just tells me application crashed. I searched and I found out that I have to convert `QGuiApplication` to `QApplication` but when I changed my `main.cpp` file into this , I got some strange errors. I'm writing a QtQuick Application using QML.
What's the correct way of converting ?

Main.cpp file :

```cpp
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    const QUrl url(u"qrc:/RadarChart/Main.qml"_qs);
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreationFailed,
        &app, []() { QCoreApplication::exit(-1); },
        Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}
```

Here are the errors :

```
:-1: error: D:/CppProjects/RadarChart/main.cpp:17: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN12QApplicationD1Ev'
:-1: error: D:/CppProjects/build-radarchart-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_MinGW_64_bit-Debug/Debug_Desktop__9a53abaa43e654f2/radarchart.8c396ce1/3a52ce780950d4d9/main.cpp.o:D:/CppProjects/RadarChart/main.cpp:7: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN12QApplicationC1ERiPPci'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Qbs Manual: Creating Dependencies to Qt Modules](https://doc.qt.io/qbs/qt-modules.html#creating-dependencies-to-qt-modules):

> The Qt modules are grouped using the prefix Qt. If your product depends on the Qt.core and Qt.network modules, you could write:
>
> ```
> Depends { name: "Qt.core" }
> Depends { name: "Qt.network" }
> ```

Based on that, you should add `Qt.widgets` module to your `.qbs` file if you want to use `QApplication`:

```
Depends { name: "Qt.widgets" }
```

This was tested on a clean QML project and it works.

**Source:**

- [How to convert QGuiApplication to QApplication ?](https://forum.qt.io/topic/147307/how-to-convert-qguiapplication-to-qapplication/4?_=1690829484139)

**Credits:**

- [jsulm](https://forum.qt.io/user/jsulm)